# .ease() - Animation of pointer should be in an arched trajectory

Tags: animation, d3.js

I'm playing around with ( https://gist.github.com/1499279 ) a custom gauge using *d3js* by Tomer. In his code, he calls `updateGauges() gauges[key].redraw(30 + 50 * Math.random() - 30 * Math.random());` to generate random numbers for the pointer to animate to. I changed it to `gauges[key].redraw(80);` so that the pointer does not re-render.

During the initial load, the pointer follows a shortest path in getting to its destination instead of animating in an arched trajectory (clock wise like how real gauges operate). When 80 is passed in as parameter, the pointer animates anti clockwise from 0. Instead, it should always follow an arched trajectory.

What do you guys think should be modified/added?

*Soln Update:

```
this.drawPointer = function(value)
{
    var delta = this.config.range / 13;
    var n=value/2;

    var head = this.valueToPoint(n, 0.85);
    var head1 = this.valueToPoint(n - delta, 0.12);
    var head2 = this.valueToPoint(n + delta, 0.12);

    var headlast = this.valueToPoint(value, 0.85);
    var head1last = this.valueToPoint(value - delta, 0.12);
    var head2last = this.valueToPoint(value + delta, 0.12);

    var tailValue = n -  (this.config.range * (1/(270/360)) / 2);
    var tail = this.valueToPoint(tailValue, 0.28);
    var tail1 = this.valueToPoint(tailValue - delta, 0.12);
    var tail2 = this.valueToPoint(tailValue + delta, 0.12);

    var tailValuelast = value -  (this.config.range * (1/(270/360)) / 2);
    var taillast = this.valueToPoint(tailValuelast, 0.28);
    var tail1last = this.valueToPoint(tailValuelast - delta, 0.12);
    var tail2last = this.valueToPoint(tailValuelast + delta, 0.12);


    var data = [head, head1, tail2, tail, tail1, head2, head];

    var line = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function(d) { return d.x })
                        .y(function(d) { return d.y })
                        .interpolate("basis");


    var pointerContainer = this.body.select(".pointerContainer");   

    var pointer = pointerContainer.selectAll("path").data([data])                                       

    pointer.enter()
            .append("svg:path")
                .attr("d", line)
                .style("fill", "#dc3912")
                .style("stroke", "#c63310")
                .style("fill-opacity", 0.7)

    pointer.transition()
                .attr("d", line) 
                .each("end", function () {      
                if (value!=0) {

                        var head = headlast;
                        var head1 = head1last;
                        var head2 = head2last;

                        var tailValue = tailValuelast;
                        var tail = taillast;
                        var tail1 = tail1last;
                        var tail2 = tail2last;

                        var data = [head, head1, tail2, tail, tail1, head2, head];

                        var line = d3.svg.line()
                                        .x(function(d) { return d.x })
                                        .y(function(d) { return d.y })
                                        .interpolate("basis");

                        var pointer = pointerContainer.selectAll("path").data([data])                                       

                        pointer.enter()
                            .append("svg:path")
                                .attr("d", line)
                                .style("fill", "#dc3912")
                                .style("stroke", "#c63310")
                                .style("fill-opacity", 0.7)

                        pointer.transition()
                                .attr("d", line) 
                                .ease("bounce")
                                .duration(600); 
                            }
                }
                )
                .duration(200);

    var fontSize = Math.round(this.config.size / 10);
    pointerContainer.selectAll("text")
                        .data([value])
                            .text(Math.round(value))
                        .enter()
                            .append("svg:text")
                                .attr("x", this.config.cx)
                                .attr("y", this.config.size - this.config.cy / 4 - fontSize)                        
                                .attr("dy", fontSize / 2)
                                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                                .text(Math.round(value))
                                .style("font-size", fontSize + "px")
                                .style("fill", "#000")
                                .style("stroke-width", "0px");
}
```

Regards,
Viswesh

Comment: What does this have to do with D?

Comment: @tjameson I'm not sure how D got tagged. Removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also new to D3, but here is my humble understanding (please correct me if I am wrong):

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y })
    .interpolate("basis");
```

Here interpolate simply change x and y value from current value to target value.

In your case, the y value needs to change from current value -> highest point(which is 100) -> to the target value.

One of the solution i can think of is add control point.

Comment: Yin, great suggestion. Thanks. 

When 80 gets passed, the pointer would first move to 40 (head, head1, head2, tail, tail1, tail2) and then end the transition at 80 (tailvaluelast, taillast, tail1last, tail2last). Once the pointer is animated to 40, a call  back function is called. 

Although the pointer does not simulate a smooth transition between the 2 end points, it looks like a special edition gauge. The notable part is the length of the pointer does not reduce too much.